# $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}}$ in 3D

Tags: exponential-function, 3d

I have the function $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}}$, which produces this graphic:

[image]

What should $f(x,y)$ be to look like a 'hill', i.e. $f(x)$ spinned about vertical axis?

Comment: you are looking for a function $f(x,y)$ that its graphic is the same as $f(x)$ rotates about the $y$ axe?

Comment: well, yes if the center of $f(x)$ would lie on $Oy$.

Comment: Actually i have found a replacement that is the Gaussian function, and looking at it i suppose that the right spinning for my $f(x)$ would be $f(x,y) = e^{-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-y}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just take $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$, i.e.
$$g(x,y)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x}}e^{-\frac{1}{y}}e^{-\frac{1}{1-y}},$$
which produces the following graph (using MATLAB):
[image]

Another choice that also leads to a 'hill-like' shape, would be to use
$$g(x,y)=e^{-a\left((\frac{1}{2}-x)^2+(\frac{1}{2}-y)^2\right)},$$
i.e. a Gaussian kernel centered at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$:

[image]
This one has $a=25$ :)

Comment: Thanks! I also found Gaussian function useful here :)
btw, is $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ always sufficient to spin a function?

Comment: In a way, yes. Namely, if you fix $x$, such that $f(x)$ is constant, say $f(x)=c$, then $g(y)=c\cdot f(y)$, such that it is just a multiple of your original function. However, if $c=0$ then $g(y)$ becomes zero, if $c<0$ then $g(y)$ flips around.